# Delphi won't run

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

If I try to run Delphi 7, I get this frightening message:

> Borland license information was found, but it is not valid for Delphi.
>   You cannot run Delphi without this information. Click the exit button
>   to exit Delphi.

Delphi was running fine this morning, but choked when I tried to load the project I'm working on.

- I reinstalled Delphi from the original disk - *same message*
- I have just done a system restore from a few days ago - *same message*

I don't know why.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

According to the [archives](http://web.archive.org/web/20080121005518/http://www.chillibear.org/delphi/license.shtml) of Chillibear, here is what you do:

1. Delete your registry.slm file from the .borland directory within your user's folder within documents and settings.

   Run the D7Reg.exe file from within your Delphi7 Bin directory.

   Follow the registration steps (you don't have to register now!)

   All done. Open Delphi7 as normal.

Comment: i believe its enough to run the D7Reg.exe and hit cancel

Comment: @ChristopherChase: I found simply running D7Reg.exe was not enough, I had to delete the registry.slm file.

Comment: @Paul-Jan: Worked for me, whew! On opening Delphi 7 the 1st time after re-registering, I got many exceptions with 3rd party plug-ins and then again trying to close the Delphi IDE. I killed Delphi7 using Task Manager then reloaded for a 2nd time, when it all worked perfectly. No clue as to why this has happened. Sonny suggested disk space issues, but that is not the case with me (unless there a corrupted sector on the HDD?). The only thing I can think of is that the PC with Delphi7 had not been used for several months. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Try to delete file documents and settings\.borland\registry.slm (of course backup at first) and rerun Delphi

Answer (score 9):

> ### [Invalid Delphi license](http://chillibear.org/2008/12/invalid-delphi-license.html)
>
> 1. Delete your **registry.slm** file from the **.borland** directory within *your
>      user's folder* within **Documents and Settings**.
> 2. Run the **D7Reg.exe** file from within your Delphi7 **Bin** directory.
> 3. Follow the registration steps (you don't have to register now!)
> 4. All done. Open Delphi7 as normal.

Using this 4 step program made my blood pressure drop to safe levels again.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You'll also encounter this similar error message when your C drive where C:\Documents and Settings\username\borland folder is located doesn't have enough disk space left to write to. You must free up as much disk space as you could or transfer some of files to another drive and the error message will simply vanish without a trace.

Answer (score 1):

Contact their support. Go at [www.embarcadero.com](http://www.embarcadero.com) The last menu option is 'Services'. From there I'd would choose http://www.embarcadero.com/support

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after the recent update to W10.  I found the slm file in C:\users\.borland and just renamed it (in case).  I was then able to run D7Reg.exe - if you try it before deleting the slm file it doesnt accept your registration details!!  I cancelled the program after it had accepted the details so that it didnt wipe all the 3rd party connections and Delphi7 now works fine.  Thank you so much for this fix.

Comment: the path to the slm file didnt translate well - it is found in C:\users\username\dotBorland

Answer (score 0):

The same message problem but with a change of hard disk for a new(copy all the partition)
The solucion change the name of the unit, becouse any program work. But maybe happend if you install in other unit and the borland to start try to find in the other name of unit.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run Delphi 7 in Windows XP compatibility mode

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way:
Restoring the **registry.slm** file from a backup did the job!

file location: **%userprofile%\.borland**

As to 'why':
Found said registry.slm file damaged after a power out.
Restore, voilá!